# Reporting with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, report

I am at the moment working on a project on Visual Studio 2010 using C#.

One of my main tasks is to print invoices with a pretty strict layout, that is, some elements have to be positioned precisely say 3 mm from each other.

I had realized this project a long time ago using Access and its report framework, and it was quite useful because it allows page footers, report footer and so on.

I wanted to know what technology I should use in this case. I'm thinking about using Crystal Reports but I don't know if I should use the Microsoft Reporting framework instead.

Could you give me some advice, and if possible, suggest me a good tutorial about that technology?

For example, do you know any specific features one of them has?

What about deployment? Any of them is easier to handle?

Comment: Why don't you just try them to see which you like best.  CR is no longer included, you can download it from SAP.

Comment: Yeah actually, I was asking for opinions. Because it can take long to do the whole report and then find out that some feature is not available. Besides, I was also wondering about deployment issues. I heard deploying CR was quite complecated somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking to do something similar and I have been playing around with this [Free Library](http://report.sourceforge.net/) as well as [this one too](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_frontpage&Itemid=1)

Comment: Did you experience any specific problem with Crystal Report or the Reporting Services from SQL Server that made you make this choice?

Comment: Personally, I would prefer to use Crystal Reports but I am transitioning from VB6 to C# so I was using it as an exercise to learn more about the syntax.

Comment: Also here is the [link](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp) for Crystal Reports for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of SQL Server, you can use [Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx).  It's a very nice environment for building and managing reports.

Is this a web app or a desktop app that you're building?

Comment: It's a desktop app, but using SQL Compact Edition (the database file is attached to the project). Hence, I don't think I can use this solution.

Comment: You can use the 'Client' version using the ReportViewer Control. It's pretty much the same things, except it's local.